# Is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x_1-2| + |x_2-1| \leq 2\}$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x_1-2| + |x_2-1| \leq 2\}$ is compact?

I know that if $x \in \mathbb{R^2}$, then the previous set would be compact. However, there is an extension, and the topology is a bit different.

Is anyone could comment this set?

Comment: Note that $x_3$ can roam freely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $C \subset \mathbb R^2$ be the set of $x = (x_1, x_2)$ that satisfy $|x_1-2| + |x_2-1| \leq 2$. Then your set is $C \times \mathbb R$. Does that look compact under the usual topology?

Comment: I know that there exist a theorem which say if $E$ is a normed vector space et $A$ compact, then $A \times E$ is a compact. So our $A$ space should be compact, right?

Comment: No, that's incorrect. In $\mathbb R^n$ under the usual topology, a subset $U$ is compact iff it is bounded and closed. $C \times \mathbb R$ is not bounded.